# Can we use id within .insertBefore() funciton jquery

Tags: jquery

Can we use the `id` attribute within the `.insertBefore()` method of jQuery? I used this function with the `class` attribute and it worked like a charm. But when I use `id`, it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 775) {
    $("#archive-product").insertBefore("#secondary");
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure an element with `id="secondary"` exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, you can**. You should have a look to [jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/).

Here I leave you a snippet.

```js
$( document ).ready( function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 775) {
    $("#archive-product").insertBefore("#secondary");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="secondary">Hi</div>
<div id="archive-product">Bye</div>
```

**So, why it is not working in my case?**

Different possible reasons:

- The jQuery library is not referenced.
- One of the elements you refer to is not existing (check carefully the *ids*)
- One of them is duplicated (jQuery will take the first of them)
- A little obvius, `$( window ).width()` is over 775px, so the condition returns `false`.
- You have some invalid JavaScript inside your script (try to delete everything but the `.insertBefore` instruction to check it out)

**UPDATE**

After reading your comment it is clear that I forgot (at least) one reason:

- There is a conflict with other JS library (use `jQuery` instead of `$` or go for [jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/))

Comment: @jayantrawat: Thank you for the comment, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `insertBefore()` accepts any Selector or htmlString or Element or Array or jQuery.
You should have a problem with the HTML markup or duplicate ID.

Here is an example: [JSnippet demo](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/340/insertBefore-with-id)

Comment: It looks like a case of duplicate ID to me.

Comment: @brute_force usually it is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Checkout the documentation of jQuery
http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/
In their example they use it with id selector

```
$( "p" ).insertBefore( "#foo" );
```